# definition of σ-algebra

Tags: measure-theory

A set $\mathcal{A}$ of subsets of $\Omega$ is called a $\sigma$-algebra if the following properties are satisfied:

$(i)$ $\Omega\in A$,

$(ii)$ $A\in \mathcal{A}\Rightarrow A^c = \Omega\setminus A\in\mathcal{A}$,

$(iii)$ $A_n\in\mathcal{A}\Rightarrow \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n\in\mathcal{A}$

I have a question about first and second properties. Doesn't second property instantly follow from first property?

Comment: No. Take any nonempty set as $\Omega$ and take $A=\{\Omega\}$. This satisfies the first and third properties but not the second.

Comment: Note that you could get the same definition from properties $2$ and $3$, along with the requirement that $\mathcal{A}$ be nonempty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is as much instantaneous: no. In fact, assume $A=\{\Omega\}$. Then (i) and also (iii) are  *instantly* satisfied, as you say. The (ii) is not: it would be satisfied only if $\emptyset\in A$, which is not the case in our assumption.

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: $\Omega = \{1,2\}$ and $\mathcal{A} = \{\Omega, \{1\}\}$